# if is_grandchild for single and category

Tags: wordpress

I've been searching around and can't seem to find (or piece together) code that checks to see if the current category OR post is a grandchild of a certain category. Basically, is there any way to properly code for:

```
<?php if ( is_grandchild(147) || in_grandchild(147) ) { do something } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_topmost_parent($post_id){
  $parent_id = get_post($post_id)->post_parent;
  if($parent_id == 0){
    return $post_id;
  }else{
    return get_topmost_parent($parent_id);
  }
}
```

try this will return top mostparent !

Comment: So, with this function I can do $cat = get_topmost_parent();, but how do I then use it to apply to only grandchild categories posts?